# Receiving null values from python mixer

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, fixtures

i'm trying to generate some fixtures to test a Flask application, using the excellente library mixer. I already used it on a Django project and worked perfectly, but on flask+sqlalchemy no matter what i do i receive null values.

```
from mixer.backend.flask import mixer
from models import Users
from myproj import app

mixer.init_app(app)

me.blend(Users)
```

That returns null.

I also tried instantiating directly the app.

```
from mixer.backend.flask import Mixer
from models import Users
from myproj import app

mixer = Mixer(app=app)

me = mixer.blend(Users)
```

Returns the same null value.

Both cases returns a autogenerated id. And is saved to the database, but all fields have Null on it.

Any idea of why?

Thanks

Comment: Did you follow the [Flask-SQLAlchemy instructions](https://github.com/klen/mixer#flask-flask-sqlalchemy)?

Comment: Yeah. The first try is exactly the instructions in the documentation. The second is me trying to figure out causes. Did i miss something?

Comment: There's a [section specifically about Flask-SQLAlchemy and arguments to `__init__`](https://github.com/klen/mixer#user-content-support-for-flask-sqlalchemy-models-that-have-__init__-arguments). Does `Users` use an `__init__` method to assign values?

Comment: No, an what's more i have created a TestModel with only a name column to explicitly test mixer with no luck whatsoever.

Comment: I can't get it to work either, I've opened an issue on the [project page on Github](https://github.com/klen/mixer/issues/20) to ask for some clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out it's a simple answer-- Mixer doesn't generate data for fields that can be null.  So either specify that in your models, for example this works:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from mixer.backend.flask import mixer

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
mixer.init_app(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        user = mixer.blend(User)
        print user.id, user.username

        # Prints: 1 collins1995
```

Or tell Mixer what fields you want it to generate if you want to keep them nullable:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from mixer import fakers as f
from mixer.backend.flask import mixer

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
mixer.init_app(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        user = mixer.blend(User, username=f.get_username(), email=f.get_email())
        print user.id, user.username, user.email

        # Prints: 1 lover_boots robinson1963@google.vn
```

Thanks to klen, the author of Mixer for [providing the solution](https://github.com/klen/mixer/issues/20).

Comment: Awesome, i actually hadn't put nullable=False on any field. That would explain how in Django it works out of the box, default behaviour is nullable=False.

Comment: Thanks @doobeh, but there is little bit more about the second case:

It is not necessary to use mixer fakers for force nullable values, Mixer has a magic attribute `mixer.R` which doing the work: `user = mixer.blend(User, username=mixer.R, email=mixer.R)`